# How to convert JSON to a Ruby hash

Tags: ruby, json, hashmap

I have a JSON object holding the following value:

```
@value = {"val":"test","val1":"test1","val2":"test2"}
```

I want to loop through it in Ruby to get the key/value pairs. When I use `@each`, it doesn't iterate through the object because it is not in the Ruby hash form:

```
@value = {"val"=>"test","val1"=>"test1","val2"=>"test2"}
```

How can I convert the above JSON object to a Ruby hash?

Answer (score 292, accepted):

```
require 'json'
value = '{"key_1":"value_1", "key_2":"value_2"}'
puts JSON.parse(value) # => {"key_1"=>"value_1","key_2"=>"value_2"}
```

Comment: `value = '{"val":"test","val1":"test1","val2":"test2"}'` could have been more readable.

Answer (score 57):

You could also use Rails' [`with_indifferent_access`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html#method-i-with_indifferent_access) method  so you could access the body with either symbols or strings.

```
value = '{"val":"test","val1":"test1","val2":"test2"}'
json = JSON.parse(value).with_indifferent_access
```

then

```
json[:val] #=> "test"

json["val"] #=> "test"
```

Comment: Does anyone know if this is more resource-intensive for larger hash objects? I'm new to Ruby/Rails, but assuming this duplicates key-value pairs?

Comment: Oh God, this was a lifesaver after 2 hours of looking for a "simple" solution. Thank you!!

Comment: it may cause issues in your specs when trying to match stubbed requests

Answer (score 7):

I'm surprised nobody pointed out JSON's [`[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#method-c-5B-5D) method, which makes it very easy and transparent to decode and encode from/to JSON.

> If object is string-like, parse the string and return the parsed result as a Ruby data structure. Otherwise generate a JSON text from the Ruby data structure object and return it.

Consider this:

```rb
require 'json'

hash = {"val":"test","val1":"test1","val2":"test2"} # => {:val=>"test", :val1=>"test1", :val2=>"test2"}
str = JSON[hash] # => "{\"val\":\"test\",\"val1\":\"test1\",\"val2\":\"test2\"}"
```

`str` now contains the JSON encoded `hash`.

It's easy to reverse it using:

```rb
JSON[str] # => {"val"=>"test", "val1"=>"test1", "val2"=>"test2"}
```

Custom objects need `to_s` defined for the class, and inside it convert the object to a Hash then use `to_json` on it.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a JSON hash hanging around somewhere, to automatically convert it into something like WarHog's version, wrap your JSON hash contents in `%q{hsh}` tags.

This seems to automatically add all the necessary escaped text like in WarHog's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nice_hash gem: https://github.com/MarioRuiz/nice_hash

```
require 'nice_hash'
my_string = '{"val":"test","val1":"test1","val2":"test2"}'

# on my_hash will have the json as a hash, even when nested with arrays
my_hash = my_string.json

# you can filter and get what you want even when nested with arrays
vals = my_string.json(:val1, :val2)

# even you can access the keys like this:
puts my_hash._val1
puts my_hash.val1
puts my_hash[:val1]
```