# How can I post JSON data with curl and use it in RoR?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json

I am building an iOS app and it needs to post to a RoR API.

To test the POST, I am running this command:

```
curl -d @/tmp/data localhost:3000/api/ratings
```

Where /tmp/data contains an array of hashes:

```
[    {        "uid": "gilt_162929239",        "rate": 1    }   ]
```

In Ruby, params looks like this:

```
[1] pry(#<Api::PromotionRatingsController>)> params
=> {"    {        \"uid\": \"good_162929239\",        \"rate\": 1    }   "=>nil,
 "format"=>"json",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"api/ratings"}
```

How do I get Rails to create the array of hashes for me to iterate over with each?

Edit: I see I was missing headers.

Adding to the curl command line:

```
--header "Accept: application/json" --header "Content-type: application/json"
```

Now, here are my params:

```
[1] pry(#<Api::PromotionRatingsController>)> params
=> {"_json"=>[{"uid"=>"good_162929239", "rate"=>1}],
 "format"=>"json",
 "action"=>"create",
 "controller"=>"api/ratings",
 "promotion_rating"=>{"_json"=>[{"uid"=>"good_162929239", "rate"=>1}]}}
```

Still not right.

Comment: Not a ruby developer, but normally you'd decode that json string, which converts it into a native data structure. Then you use your host language's array/object/hash/whatever manipulation tools as you would with any other native structure.

Comment: In RoR IIRC, it should automatically convert JSON data into native objects.  But it's not happening for me.

Comment: Again, I sporadically work on RoR so did'nt post this as an answer. Can you extract the JSON string from the `params` hash, assign it to an object, and then use the `json` gem as explained in this post ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964282/convert-json-to-ruby-hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#json-xml-parameters):

> if you’ve turned on config.wrap_parameters in your initializer or
>   calling wrap_parameters in your controller, you can safely omit the
>   root element in the JSON/XML parameter. The parameters will be cloned
>   and wrapped in the key according to your controller’s name by default.

So, my guess is that you either need to include a root element, or set `config.wrap_parameters`.