# Regexp, can't match many elements contained in an array (json)

Tags: ruby, regex, json, pattern-matching

I have trouble doing a regexp, and I don't know how to formulate the questions, so better than words, here is an example

## String

```
"medias": [
    {
      "height": 800,
      "id": "",
      "origin": "google",
      "thumbnail": {
        "height": 94,
        "url": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTF_KeDfHAxLuvCoYkuKUcwPKpxHfjt19g-E0uhsV20rLGf6VbJ--NFKCuO",
        "width": 150
      },
      "title": "144779-cat-cats.jpg",
      "type": "image",
      "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-bemqYIv9dPw/UTsFD0yJsBI/AAAAAAAAAZI/1zrKmdolPLY/s0-d/144779-cat-cats.jpg",
      "width": 1280
    },
    {
      "height": 300,
      "id": "",
      "origin": "google",
      "thumbnail": {
        "height": 94,
        "url": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR60TwME2D02rjeROsOlHSMdk5AkrtwPwJIhsXBqoOoISUA95rXpKXihL4",
        "width": 124
      },
      "title": "cats-in-sink.jpeg",
      "type": "image",
      "url": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-zrZJg2qJQlI/Tg9kwdqbsrI/AAAAAAAAAEQ/Oal8KLLfItk/cats-in-sink.jpeg",
      "width": 397
    }
]
```

## Regexp

```
"medias": \[
   ([{
      "height": \d+[,|]
      "id": ".*"[,|]
      "origin": ".*"[,|]
      "thumbnail": {
        "height": \d+[,|]
        "url": ".*"[,|]
        "width": \d+[,|]
      }[,|]
      "title": ".*"[,|]
      "type": ".*"[,|]
      "url": ".*"[,|]
      "width": \d+[,|]
    }[,|]]*)[,|]
\][,|]
```

Just the middle part of the regexp, between (), works fine. but when I add the `media wrapper` around it gets broken.

```
"medias": \[
 ....................
 ....................
 ...........[,|]
\][,|]
```

[Here you'll find the middle part matching](http://rubular.com/r/tZWdrMWRAR)

[And here you'll find the complete regexp that is broken](http://rubular.com/r/NCLTVtA1CK)

Any Idea ?

Comment: Using a huge regex to match something like that is asking for trouble. JSON has a well-defined format; you'd probably find it a lot easier to use a JSON parser instead of a regex.

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `json_decode()` in php instead

```
$array = json_decode($json_object);
```

Comment: You can't know because i didn't mention it in the question but i'm actually using ruby. So I should do: `hash = JSON.parse(myjsonstring)`
A good post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7964378/2199605)

Comment: Thanks. It seems everything is under control :)