# Saving multiple entries to database from Ajax request in Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, dynamic

I have the following AJAX Post

```
var BandName = $("#bandName").val();

$.ajax({url:('/albums/create'), method: ('post'), 
        data: {"album": {"name":BandName}}, dataType: "json", success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        } 
    });
```

Example of Returned JSON data...

https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=weezer&entity=album

BANDS CONTROLLER:

```
def create
  @album = Album.create(album_params)
end
```

SCHEMA:

```
create_table "albums", force: true do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.string   "releaseDate"
t.string   "artWorkUrl"
t.integer  "band_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
```

I'd like to iterate through the returned JSON Data, saving the appropriate values...i.e., Name, release data, artWorkUrl... to my database. but am unclear where and how I should do that. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I'n unclear as to what you mean. using say .each on each member of the array seems a fairly trivial question???

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964282/convert-json-to-ruby-hash). Convert it to a `hash` then use the hash to write to your database.

Comment: your ajax call syntax is wrong, is ajax call going??