# Extracting data from Deeply Nested JSON in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

Have a Json out put like

```
{
  "query": {
    "results": {
      "industry": [
        {
          "id": "112",
          "name": "Agricultural Chemicals",
          "company": [
            {
              "name": "Adarsh Plant",
              "symbol": "ADARSHPL"
            },
            {
              "name": "Agrium Inc",
              "symbol": "AGU"
            }
    },
    ]
    {
          "id": "914",
          "name": "Water Utilities",
          "company": [
            {
              "name": "Acque Potabili",
              "symbol": "ACP"
            },
            {
              "name": "Water Resources Group",
              "symbol": "WRG"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Need the out put like - Company Name, Company Symbol, Company id,
Company id name

and example of output would be

Adarsh Plant, ADARSHPL, 112, Agricultural Chemicals
Agrium Inc, AGU, 112, Agricultural Chemicals
Acque Potabili, ACP, 914, Water Utilities
Water Resources Group, WRG, 914, Water Utilities

Any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your sample json, but we'll talk about it later.

Assuming your json data converted to hash object already like this:

```
json={
  "query"=> {
    "results"=> {
      "industry"=> [
        {
          "id"=> "112",
          "name"=> "Agricultural Chemicals",
          "company"=> [
            {
              "name"=> "Adarsh Plant",
              "symbol"=> "ADARSHPL"
            },
            {
              "name"=> "Agrium Inc",
              "symbol"=> "AGU"
            }
          ]
        },
       {    
          "id"=> "914",
          "name"=> "Water Utilities",
          "company"=> [
            {
              "name"=> "Acque Potabili",
              "symbol"=> "ACP"
            },
            {
              "name"=> "Water Resources Group",
              "symbol"=> "WRG"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You can use inject and map to handle the two level array of industry, inject will iterate the outer array:

```
json["query"]["results"]["industry"].inject([]){|m,o|
  m += o["company"].map{|x| [x["name"],x["symbol"],o["id"],o["name"]]}
}
```

result is an array of arrays with the order as you wish:

```
=> [["Adarsh Plant", "ADARSHPL", "112", "Agricultural Chemicals"], 
    ["Agrium Inc", "AGU", "112", "Agricultural Chemicals"], 
    ["Acque Potabili", "ACP", "914", "Water Utilities"], 
    ["Water Resources Group", "WRG", "914", "Water Utilities"]]
```

If you  want get a string delimited by comma, you could chain on `.flatten.join(",")` at the end.

```
json["query"]["results"]["industry"].inject([]){|m,o|
  m += o["company"].map{|x| [x["name"],x["symbol"],o["id"],o["name"]]}
}.flatten.join(",")
```

Result:

```
=> Adarsh Plant,ADARSHPL,112,Agricultural Chemicals,Agrium Inc,AGU,112,Agricultural Chemicals,Acque Potabili,ACP,914,Water Utilities,Water Resources Group,WRG,914,Water Utilities
```

**The typo of your json data:**

In the middle  `}, ] {` should be changed to `] },{` .

**Convert json to hash**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7964378/3630826

Comment: I checked out the code... the output is like that itself.. as given in original post... I think the output is neither pure json nor hash.. due to that error.. the extraction is troublesome..