# Ruby/Rails: each do loop range from another loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm using the following each do loop to pull in data from a JSON file and make it usable on my site.

```
<% data.games.ronedoneb.each do |s| %>
```

This is working great. What I'm wanting to do is to specify a range that will be used, like so:

```
<% data.games.ronedoneb[(0..5)].each do |s| %>
```

What I'm wanting to do however, is change the range (0..5) based on fields within another JSON file, the range will always be blocks of 6 so: (0..5), (6..11), (12..17) etc etc.

This is what I've tried to do is below:

```
<% data.games.ronedoneb[(<%= ss[:z1] %>..<%= ss[:z2] %>)].each do |s| %>
```

This doesn't work, I hoped that I'd be able to pull the z1 and z2 results from the first JSON file.

Is there a way that I can do this? Is there something I'm missing?

Below are examples of the JSON being used.

**JSON 1**

```
"Ar": "1",
"Br": "0",
"Round": "1",
"Game": "3",
"Date": "Thursday, 5 February 2015",
"Day": "1",
"z1": "12",
"z2": "17"
```

**JSON 2**

```
"Game": "1",
"AR": "9",
"Day": "1",
"GPMB": "351",
"DR": "2",
"CSB": "275",
"GPMR": "360",
"AB": "1",
"Round": "1",
"CSp10R": "60",
"GoldR": "13.2",
"DB": "2",
"CSR": "222",
"GoldB": "12.9",
"KDAR": "6.50",
"Blue": "23.7",
"CSat10B": "79",
"KB": "5",
"KDAB": "3.00",
"KR": "4",
"CSat10R": "76"
```

Comment: Are you doing this loop to group data in a nested loop ? like loop 1 => 0-5, loop 2 => 6-11, till the end? and all process the data in the same way? cause if so there's a better way to handle this.

Comment: Yes that is what I'm trying to do. How would you suggest I do this?

Comment: `ronedoneb` is an array right ?

Comment: It is the JSON 2 example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `<%=` in the place you did. Please try something like:

```
<% data.games.ronedoneb[(ss[:z1].to_i..ss[:z2].to_i)].each do |s| %>
```

Comment: I gave that a go and it wouldn't produce a result:  no implicit conversion from nil to integer

Comment: Ok, working with that, it is pulling the value from the z1 & z2 field in the JSON, so making progress. It seems as though it is only sticking with the first z1/z2 scanned and staying with that for each loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ruby's already built in enumerable method `each_slice` you specify the slice length and it will cut the array into slices with that length, then pass the slices to the block.

You'll probably need to convert the json into a hash, but that's easy,

```
data.games.ronedoneb.each_slice(5) do |slice|
  slice.each do |item|
    #process here
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm happy to give that a go however this project is the first time I've used rails so I've not had to convert JSON into a hash before. I'm learning everything as I go. Looking over this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964282/convert-json-to-ruby-hash seems straight forward enough. How do I include this in my erb file? <% XYZ %> for each line followed by a <% end %> after all the lines? Or do I set this up in an external file?

Comment: The conversion is better done in the controller, it would be something like this `@data = JSON.parse(data.games.ronedoneb)` then in the view just do `@data.each_slice(5) do |slice|`

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'm going to have a play around with this and see if I can get my head around it.

Comment: If an answer solves your question you should click on the check mark which becomes green after that.