# Updating a json object from Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, activerecord

I'm working with an object (Account) in Rails that I want to update, and have encountered a JSON object when I try to update a Stripe attribute:

```
irb(main):001:0> account = Account.find(1);
irb(main):002:0* subscription = account.subscription
[■]   Account Load (2.2ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
=> #<Stripe::Subscription:0x35fbed4 id=sub_CPQps6J7nkb2hL> JSON: {
  "id": "jhlakdjfhbjbf",
  "object": "subscription",

  "default_tax_rates": [

  ],
  "discount": null,
  "ended_at": null,
  "livemode": true,
  "metadata": {},
  "pending_setup_intent": null,
  "plan": {"id":"free-monthly","object":"plan","active":true,...},
  "quantity": 1,
  "schedule": null,
}
irb(main):003:0> plan = subscription.plan
=> #<Stripe::Plan:0x35b9994 id=free-monthly> JSON: {
  "id": "tier-1",
  "object": "plan",
  "active": true,
  "aggregate_usage": null,
  "amount": 0,
  "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
  "created": 1491333713,
  "currency": "usd",
  "interval": "month"
}
```

When I try to update `plan` by `plan.update!(id:"tier-0")`, I run into problems, (JSON); how do I account for this to update the `plan` for my `account`?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is you convert it into hash object. Then, update it's value and then convert it back ( if necessary, but, I think you might want to do more with this object )

consider this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964282/convert-json-to-ruby-hash)

```
require 'json'


plan = JSON.parse(subscription.plan) # Now, plan is a hash
plan[:id] = 'tier-0'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would update the json column with the required key-value pairs while keeping rest of the keys as it is.

```
account = Account.find(1)
plan = account.subscription['plan']
plan = {'plan' => plan.merge(id: "tier-0") }
account.update_attribute(:subscription, account.subscription.deep_merge(plan))
```

Comment: Wouldn't I have to do this at the plan level though (skipped in this solution)? The subscription level has its own, totally different `id`.