# Return specific values from array of hashes - JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-6

Hi am learning rails and in my app, I'm getting values in json format from
`res = @client.spots(params[:location][:lat], params[:location][:lng], :types => ['restaurant','food'], :radius => 500)`

in my res object, I'm getting these values

```html
{
  "json_result_object": {
    "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
    "geometry": {
      "location": {
        "lat": 31.4734563,
        "lng": 74.2794873
      },
      
    },
    "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
    "name": "CP Five Star",
    "opening_hours": {
      "open_now": true
    }
      }
    ],
    "place_id": "ChIJjfE-TdoDGTkRMom8KQfI9Uc",
    "plus_code": {
      "compound_code": "F7FH+9Q Lahore, Pakistan",
      "global_code": "8J3PF7FH+9Q"
    },
   
  },
  "reference": "ChIJjfE-TdoDGTkRMom8KQfI9Uc",
  "place_id": "ChIJjfE-TdoDGTkRMom8KQfI9Uc",
  "vicinity": "Bilal Arcade, Abdul Haque Road, Block G Block G Phase 1 Johar Town, Lahore",
  "lat": 31.4734563,
  "lng": 74.2794873,
  "viewport": {
    "northeast": {
      "lat": 31.4748154802915,
      "lng": 74.28081473029151
    },
    "southwest": {
      "lat": 31.4721175197085,
      "lng": 74.2781167697085
    }
  },
  "name": "CP Five Star",
  "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/restaurant-71.png",
  "types": [
    "restaurant",
    "food",
    "point_of_interest",
    "establishment
  
}
```

now I just want to return a JSON array containing just the values below  place_id , name , lat
lng , icon

& Sorry I'm using image just to show my actual response in terminal [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdM7q.png)

Comment: Your json is not correct. You need to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/7964378/297087

Comment: im taking this from json editor

Comment: @Salil i updated my question with the actual image from the terminal please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, at the end, I find the solution. res is an array and there are multiple hashes in this array, As I'm getting this from Google Places API, so if someone wants to access the name, latitude, longitude, place_id of nearby restaurants he can do it easily by .Map by the following code.

```html
resturants =res.map { |a| {id: a.place_id ,  name: a.name , lat: a.lat, lng: a.lng , icon: a.icon}}
    json_response "Successfully retrive data" , true, {Resturant: resturants }, :ok
```

Note: json_response is my function from application controller you can use render json as well.

More over if you want array of arrays you can do it easily by

```html
res.pluck(:name, :place_id , :lat , :lng, :icon)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check what your res object type is by doing `res.class`; if it is not a hash already, you can follow the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7964378/297087) to convert it to hash.

with the res hash you can just return JSON Array like this -

`[res["place_id"], res["name"], res["lat"], res["lng"], res["icon"]]`

Comment: res class is array